# Would appreciate any assistance after a failed Homebrew command when upgrading qt@5 ... received an SHA256 mismatch error

Tags: macos, qt5, homebrew, sha256

Attempts to run brew upgrade `qt@5` on a Mac running macOS Catalina results in a `SHA256` mismatch error:

---

```
Expected: ed082ed3cac51158ede4a0f4236eedf99c0981b3451c69f34e116fa8487fa333

Actual: 70b87c38dee827b36ea853e602edeb2df1eec5d098646e3dc1a3d3f2ab2e6459
```

File:

```
/Users/leftcoast/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads
/3ffa4658a7ec539205ee8592c5513ae1f0252b437858c02005e3d24973f5d98a--ee7aed5e1020fa88f86777701948c8a236db4fc5.patch
```

To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.

---

Any insights or comments to deal the error greatly appreciated!

Over the last few months, I've attempted to run 'brew upgrade qt@5', and each time received the same SHA256 mismatch error.

Comment: Having the same problem today with the same file and same expected and actual shas, on Pop OS 22.04. Deleting the file did not help

Comment: I don't have any experience w/ homebrew but I did get past it yesterday by downloading the formula file from github, changing the expected sha256 in the file, and installing that edited formula file i.e. instead of `brew install qt@5` I did `brew install ./qt@5.rb`. This was where I got the file: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/25fc27ecaf318be6e95ed97e8f79934d69122bd6/Formula/qt%405.rb

Comment: @Drew Wiens - Thank you for the referral... I'm not familiar with that site (and don't access past the paywall) ... any specifics where I might find that file?

Comment: Sir, the link is the file

Comment: @Drew Wiens - Thank you again for the comment and suggestion. I am very much a novice at all this ... I see the `cho-m qt@5: update 5.15.8_1 bottle.` at the top of the page and some code below ... can you tell me what I am looking for therein? I clicked on `Go to file` at the top of the page but did not see any reference to `Qt` in the subsequent list? Thanks again!

Comment: Don't know if I'm making any progress, but I re-attempted to run `brew upgrade qt@5` to do more research on the issue of the `SHA256 mismatch error` and found that something has changed ... the mismatch error no longer appears, but instead the upgrade stops when attempting to access the `https://code.qt.io/qt/qtwebengine.git` web site. Instead, I was successful (after installing MacPorts) in downloading the `qt5-qtwebengine` at `https://ports.macports.org/port/qt5-qtwebengine/`. After all that, `brew upgrade qt@5` still could not access `https://code.qt.io/qt/qtwebengine.git`.

Comment: There seems to be progress at updating `brew upgrade qt@5` (as if someone is working behind the scenes to allow for qt@5 to be upgraded) but in the end the process still hangs on what appears to be an inaccessible website for the qtwebengine. I'll keep at my research to attempt to find out what is happening, but I'm beginning to think someone is in the middle of completing an upgrade to the qt@5 upgrade process, and I'll just have to wait until they have completed their work. Thanks to those who have contributed help and assistance earlier, but I think I may be in a holding pattern for a bit.